# Implicit super constructor Seat() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Tags: java, eclipse

I have read some of the other questions relating to this topic and was honestly quite lost as to the answers provided and the ones i did understand did not seem to work.

I am in an intro to ap comp sci course so simpler answers would be appreciated. I am getting an error with my Airplane constructor which error is what is above and have no idea how to solve it i tried using the super method but maybe i did it wrong since the error was still present.

Airplane class:

```
public class Airplane {

    private Seat[][] seats;
    public static final int FIRST_CLASS = 1;
    public static final int ECONOMY = 2;
    private static final int FC_ROWS = 5;
    private static final int FC_COLS = 4;
    private static final int ECONOMY_ROWS = 5;
    private static final int ECONOMY_COLS = 6;

    public Airplane() {
        seats = new Seat[FC_ROWS][ECONOMY_COLS];
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < FC_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ECONOMY_COLS; j++) {
                str = str + seats[i][j].toString();
            }
            str += "\n";
        }
        return str;
    }

    public class Seat {

        private int seatType;
        private boolean isReserved;
        public static final int WINDOW = 1;
        public static final int AISLE = 2;
        public static final int CENTER = 3;

        public Seat(int inSeatType) {
            seatType = inSeatType;
            isReserved = false;
        }

        public int getSeatType() {
            return seatType;
        }

        public void reserveSeat() {
            isReserved = true;
        }

        public boolean isAvailable() {
            if (isReserved = false) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            if (isReserved == false) {
                return "*";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The current code has no compilation error. Though it'll throw a `NPE`, but that's secondary. Post the code snippet which actually showed the error you've mentioned in your question.

Comment: Your CIDE is riddled with bugs. Here's another the others haven't mentioned: the dimensions of your array of seats makes no sense

Comment: I have a feeling we're not seeing all the relevant code here... My guess is that you have a subclass of Seat that you're not showing us.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have defined one constructor `Seat(int)`. By default Java will have a no arg constructor `Seat()` in case there are no constructors defined . Since you have defined one, you will also have to define a no arg constructor `Seat()` in case you are invoking Seat() from any part of your code 
Also `if (isReserved = false)` will assign `false` to `isReserved`. Always use == (or equals() as case may be to compare). Here, since it is boolean, you should use `if (!isReserved)`

Edit: based on the comments, removed the part where obj creation on array definition was mentioned

Comment: `seats = new Seat[FC_ROWS][ECONOMY_COLS];` won't call any `Seat` constructor(with or without arguments).

Comment: R.J so how would i go about fixing that problem?

Comment: alright for some reason the isReserved error fixed that error although my thing doesn't work that error is gone at least. thnx

Comment: You don't need a default constructor to create an array. This should not be an accepted answer imho.

Answer (score 2):

though your code will have no such compilation error. I'll clarify the answer for the question-title:

whenever there is inheritance, and sub class' object is created, the constructor of sub-class calls the constructor of all super classes in hierarchy.(till Object) By default, it calls a no-arg constructor. (to remind, jvm generates the one no-arg if you have not defined any constructor, but if you have defined, jvm will not provide any, you must provide it.)

if you have provided any other constructor in super class, other than no-arg constructor, the sub class, which is expecting a no-arg constructor, wont be able to find it, since neither you have defined nor the jvm will provide bcz of presence of other constructor.

to avoid this, you have two option, either have a no-arg constructor in super class or call any existing constructor of super from sub-class constructor using `super`.

```
subClass(){
super(<params>)
}
```

Comment: I see no `INHERITANCE` in the code posted by the OP. Neither has the OP mentioned that in the **QUESTION-STATEMENT**.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not provided any such information in your question, I'll take a chance.

I'm guessing you have a subclass of `Seat` that you're not showing us. Since `Seat` has no default constructor (constructor without arguments), in the constructor(s) of your subclass, you need to explicitly invoke `super` calling the correct `Seat` constructor. For example, this will not work:

```
public class MySeat extends Seat {

    // just an example constructor. Could be a constructor with any arguments
    public MySeat() {
        // Will not work, since the constructor Seat() does not exist, and Java tries to invoke this constructor if no super call is given.
    }
}
```

Instead, you need to do

```
public class MySeat extends Seat {

    // Just an example constructor. Your constructor can take any arguments, but you need to invoke the correct super constructor
    public MySeat(int seatType) {
        super(seatType);
    } 
}
```